# How to add if statement to return variable on a function

Tags: javascript, html

This one must seem simple for most of you, but its not for me so any help would be appreciated. How do I change one of the variables on the return part of my function? Do I just the add variable clock = and add the if statements below like so?

```
if (ms  > than 86400000) {clock =  days + " " + hours};
```

or is it like this?

```
if (ms > than 3600000) return clock : hours + ":" + minutes.
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
if (DateDiff("ms", now, TestDue) >= 0) {
    var Date1 = new Date();
    var Date2 = Date.parse(Date1);
    var TestLate1 = Date.parse(TestLate);
    var TestDue1 = Date.parse(TestDue);
    var TestLate2 = convertMS(TestLate1 - Date2).clock;
    var TestDue2 = convertMS(TestDue1 - Date2).clock;
    var TestDiff = convertMS(TestLate1 - TestDue1).clock;
    tto = "../Images/Blue-120-Button.png";
    ttt = "Test Start " + TestDue2;
    ttm = "../Images/Blue-120-ButtonMouseOver.png";
    ttd = "Test will start in " + TestDue2 + ", will be due in " + (TestDiff) + " after that and will be late on " + TestLate + ".";
    C3color = "#FFFFFF";
    C3Mcolor = "#FFFF00";
    ASTRIS = "../Images/BlueTestB.png";
    ASTRIS2 = "../Images/BlueTestB2.png";
```

so that's the part of the function I need to implement different times for.

```
function convertMS(ms) {
    days = Math.floor(ms / 86400000), // 1 Day = 86400000 Milliseconds
    hours = Math.floor((ms % 86400000) / 3600000), // 1 Hour = 3600000 Milliseconds
    minutes = Math.floor((ms % 3600000) / 60000), // 1 Minutes = 60000 Milliseconds
    seconds = Math.floor(((ms % 360000) % 60000) / 1000) // 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds

    if (minutes.toString().length == 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    };
    if (seconds.toString().length == 1) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds
    };

//need to change the conditions with if statements for clock//
    return {
        days: days,
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds,
        clock: days + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
    };
}
```

Comment: Where are your variables declared? You seem to be missing a `var` because you have commas at the end... And the semicolon.

Comment: there above in a different function

Comment: That's how you do it. Could you show the code you're having problems with?

Comment: What do you mean in a different function? `var` creates _local_ variables that won't be available outside of that function. What you're basically doing is creating a bunch of globals; they're not the same variables.

Comment: well so far that returns days hours minutes and seconds, but I need it to return different time formats for different spans of time.

Comment: So why don't you do it? What is the problem you're having with it?

Comment: I don't know how to implement if statements for different time formats for different amounts of time.

Comment: if milliseconds is above 86400000 I need the clock to return days + hours if its above 3600000 I need clock to return hours + minutes...

Comment: `if( ms > 86400000 ) return ...` or what am I missing?

Comment: I tried that, where do I put that in the function can you answer with the correct formatting?

Comment: I need some thing like this `if(ms >=86400000) days + hours` `if(ms >3600000) hours + minutes` `if(ms >=60000) minutes + seconds` if(ms >=0) seconds`

Comment: I don't understand why do people insist on making it bad to ask a question is my question that awful it needs to be down voted??? haha whatever happen to there no such thing as a bad question. I don't know how to implement a if statement for returning time format for certain amounts of time. whats wrong with that?

Comment: It's just really baffling how it's possible that you don't know how to use if statements and variables since based on the rest of the code you seem to have a basic grasp of how they work. Unless the code is copied from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that way:

```
function convertMS(ms) {
    days = Math.floor(ms / 86400000), // 1 Day = 86400000 Milliseconds
    hours = Math.floor((ms % 86400000)/ 3600000), // 1 Hour = 3600000 Milliseconds
    minutes = Math.floor((ms % 3600000) / 60000), // 1 Minutes = 60000 Milliseconds
    seconds = Math.floor(((ms % 360000) % 60000) / 1000); // 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds

    if (minutes.toString().length == 1 ) {minutes = "0" + minutes};
    if (seconds.toString().length == 1 ) {seconds = "0" + seconds};

    var clock = '';
    if(ms > 86400000) {
        clock = days + " " + hours;
    } else if(ms > 3600000 && ms < 86400000) {
        clock = hours + ":" + minutes;
    } else if(ms > 60000 && ms < 3600000) {
        clock = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        clock = seconds;
    }

    return {
        days : days,
        hours : hours,
        minutes : minutes,
        seconds : seconds,
        clock :  clock
    };
}
```

Comment: and if its above 60000 ms I need it to say minutes + seconds and if its above 0ms I nee dit to say seconds only.

Comment: I just updated my answer. It should work as you expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're looking for the ternary operator. This might point you in the right direction:

```
return  ms > 86400000 ? days + " " + hours : hours + ":" + minutes
```

Or something like that. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for more, and you should be able to easily adapt it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate variable for formatting the time and you can modify it as much as you want before returning the final object.

```
function convertMS(ms) {
    var days = Math.floor(ms / 86400000), // 1 Day = 86400000 Milliseconds
    hours = Math.floor((ms % 86400000)/ 3600000), // 1 Hour = 3600000 Milliseconds
    minutes = Math.floor((ms % 3600000) / 60000), // 1 Minutes = 60000 Milliseconds
    seconds = Math.floor(((ms % 360000) % 60000) / 1000) // 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds

    if (minutes.toString().length == 1 ) {minutes = "0" + minutes}
    if (seconds.toString().length == 1 ) {seconds = "0" + seconds}

    var clockFormat;

    if( days > 0 ) {
        clockFormat = days + " " + hours;
    }
    else if( hours > 0 ) {
        clockFormat = hours + ":" + minutes;
    }
    else {
        clockFormat = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    return {
        days : days,
        hours : hours,
        minutes : minutes,
        seconds : seconds,
        clock : clockFormat
    };
}
```